# check the update command, m i doing mistake in its syntax?

Tags: sql, vb.net

his there all,
i'm working on a cms, while trying the update command to update the records, its not working.

here's m complete code for update,

```
Dim ID, RegNo, BedNo, BedType, Charges, PatName, PatAge, PatAddr, Phone, CheckupDate, Disease, BloodGroup, Doctor, Remarks As String

    RegNo = txtRegNo.Text
    BedNo = CmbBedNo.SelectedItem.ToString()
    BedType = CmbBedType.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Charges = txtCharges.Text
    PatName = txtPatName.Text
    PatAge = txtPatAge.Text
    PatAddr = txtPatAdd.Text
    Phone = txtPhone.Text
    CheckupDate = txtDate.Text
    Disease = txtDisease.Text
    BloodGroup = cmbBloodGrp.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Doctor = cmbDoctor.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Remarks = txtRemarks.Text

    ID = txtRegNo.Text

    Dim conStudent As New OleDbConnection
    Dim comStudent As New OleDbCommand


    conStudent.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\DBProject\hspms.mdb"
    conStudent.Open()

    comStudent.CommandText = "UPDATE AdmitPt SET ID =" & ID & ", Bedcategory='" & BedType & "', BedNo=" & BedNo & ", BedCharges=" & Charges & ", PtName='" & PatName & "', PtAge=" & PatAge & ", Address='" & PatAddr & "', PhoneNo='" & Phone & "', Dates='" & CheckupDate & "', Disease='" & Disease & "', BloodGroup='" & BloodGroup & "', Doctor='" & Doctor & "', Remarks='" & Remarks & "' WHERE ID=" & RegNo

    comStudent.Connection = conStudent

    comStudent.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    If (comStudent.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
        MsgBox("record successfully updated")
    End If

    conStudent.Close()
```

one thing, that the fields named with ID, BedNo, BedCharges, Age  are set to Number as data type.

Comment: If something is not working, you really need to give the error message, or some sort of indication as to *what* isn't working if you want to get useful answers. Furthermore, you should really be using query parameters, rather than string concatenation, as you are vulnerable to SQL injection at the moment (not to mention the fact you'll get errors whenever someone has an apostrophe in their name)

Comment: there's no error message, but databse is not updated after running the query..

Comment: Then either the code updating the database is not executed or the part in the WHERE clause is not working as expected and kind of blocks UPDATE

Comment: anybody here to help?
@Iridium, nimdil

Comment: Did you get the MessageBox with the success message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, switch to a parameterized query. This will remove any possibilities of Sql Injection, but also avoid the problems with quoting strings, parsing decimal numbers and dates

```
Dim conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\DBProject\hspms.mdb"
Dim cmdText =   "UPDATE AdmitPt SET ID =?, Bedcategory=?, BedNo=?, BedCharges=?, " & _
                "PtName=?, PtAge=?, Address=?, PhoneNo=?, Dates=?, Disease=?, " & _
                "BloodGroup=?, Doctor=?, Remarks=? WHERE ID=?"
Using conStudent = new OleDbConnection(conString)
Using comStudent = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conStudent)
     conStudent.Open()
     comStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToInt32(ID))
     comStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", BedType)
     comStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToInt32(BedNo))
     comStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Convert.ToDecimal(Charges))
     .... and so on for every other question marks in the cmdText ....
     .... respecting the exact order of the fields ...................
     .... try also to pass the correct datatype for every non string field
    If (comStudent.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
        MsgBox("record successfully updated")
    End If
End Using
End Using
```